# Prevent Negative numbers for Age without using client side validation

Tags: java

I have an issue in Core java.
Consider the Employee class having an attribute called age.

```
class Employee{           
      private int age;     
      public void setAge(int age);     
}
```

My question is how do i restrict/prevent setAge(int age) method such that it accepts only positive numbers and it should not allow negative numbers,

`Note: This has to be done without using client side validation.how do i achieve it using Java/server side Validation only.The validation for age attribute should be handled such that no exception is thrown`

Comment: There is no point saying you don't want an exception thrown, you have to say what you do want to happen and thats what you should implement. When a waiter takes you order, do you start with the meals you don't want?

Comment: @Peter i do understand.this was asked in an interview ysday.hence im posting the same question and the intwer told me there is an laternate solution as well which he did not reveal

Comment: What are you planning on doing if someone enters a negative number? Are you going to tell the user at all?

Comment: Thanks all @jjnguy and the entire team has help me to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply have to validate the input from the user in the method:

```
public void setAge(int age) {
    if (age < 0) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age cannot be negative.");
    // setter logic
}
```

If you cannot throw an exception then you might wanna try:

```
public boolean setAge(int ageP) {
    // if our age param is negative, set age to 0
    if (ageP < 0) 
        this.age = 0
    else 
        this.age = ageP;
    // return true if value was good (greater than 1) 
    // and false if the value was bad
    return ageP >= 0;
}
```

You can return whether or not the value was valid.

Comment: hi @jjnguy sorry.but no exception has to be thrown

Comment: @Deepak, see my second option.  That may do what you want.

Comment: @Nishant, haha, yup.  I've had lots of practice at this.

Comment: @jinguy: This will always return false because you set age to 0 if it's less than 0.

Comment: @jjnguy this will always return false...could you help me again

Comment: @Deepak, it won't. For negative it will return true.

Answer (score 0):

Although you say you can't throw an exception, you don't really say what you want to do if the value passed is negative.

You've got to pass the failure in the validation back to the caller some way.

If you want your bean to do this, when you call your setAge method, it's either got to throw an exception or return a value.

So your options are:

```
public void setAge(int age) {
    if (age < 0) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Age cannot be negative.");
    this.age = age;
}
```

or

```
public boolean setAge(int age) {
    if(age < 0) 
        return false;

    this.age = age;
    return true;
}
```

I guess you don't want to do the second option either since setters don't normally return a value.

If you don't want to do either of these, then put a test in your caller prior to calling the setAge method.

Answer (score 0):

For javabean validation, you should consider using a framework such as [JGoodies Validation](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/validationdemo/) or [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html).

Both are very good frameworks. The Hibernate library is a JSR-303 standard and it is annotation-based. It integrates well with Spring. JGoodies validation integrates very well with JGoodies binding if you also happen to be using your JavaBeans in a Swing GUI.