# Is there any library for refined types in php?

Tags: php, types, refinement-type

Is there any library for refined types in php that can allow me to do something like this?

```
function getAge(int positive $age){
...
}

getAge(-1) // error -1 < 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've never heard of anything way to declare signed or unsigned Integers in PHP - just put a check or make a helper method.

Comment: Actually, a doubly check - look at the BC Math library - http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.bc.php - I've not needed to use this in 5 years as a PHP developer, but it could be useful.

Comment: Refinement types are not part of the core.  
You could create a UInt or Age Type and expect that with a typehint. The Check and Exception would happen in the Constructor of the Object.  `function getAge(Age $age) {};  $input = -1; try { $age = new Age($input); } catch (...  // throws Exception  ` like this [Java-Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899562/prevent-negative-numbers-for-age-without-using-client-side-validation#answer-4899590)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to implement Refinement-Types at the engine level. No one did this yet.

Or use a userland Preprocessor, like http://github.com/marcioAlmada/yay.

Or implement the refined types as Value Objects, e.g.

```
class PositiveInteger 
{
    private $value;

    public static function assertValid(int $value) {
        if ($value < 0) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Not positive");
        }
    }

    public function __construct(int $value) 
    {
        static::assertValid($value);
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function getValue(): int 
    {
        return $this->value;
    }

    public function __toString(): string 
    {
        return (string) $this->value;
    }
}
```

However, this means the int is no longer a scalar and cannot be used in the same way as you'd use a scalar, e.g. all operations would need to be methods. You won't be able to do `$age++` anymore.